# Override Directive Variable in Angular2

Tags: angular

Such Directive:

```
export class SuchDirective {

    title = "SuchDirectiveTitle"
    ...
}
```

Such Component importing such directive:

```
@Component({
    directives: [SuchDirective]
})

export class SuchComponent {
    title = "OverriddenDirectiveTitle" // not working
}
```

How to solve such problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an argument to `SuchDirective` using the `@Input` decorator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[suchDirective]'
})
export class SuchDirective {
  @Input('suchDirective') title: string;
  ...
}
```

And then change the title sending arguments to it like:

```
@Component({
  directives: [SuchDirective],
  template: `
    ...
    <div [suchDirective]="'some str'">this one uses the string 'some str' as title</div>
    ...
    <div [suchDirective]="title">this one uses the SuchComponent's title property</div>
    ...
  `
})
export class SuchComponent {
  title = "OverriddenDirectiveTitle"
}
```

---

#### Update:

Per comments, in case `SuchDirective` is a `@Component` and has a template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'such-directive',
  template: `This is my title {{ title }}`
})
export class SuchDirective {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

And use it like:

```
@Component({
  directives: [SuchDirective],
  template: `
    ...
    Passing a fixed string as title:
    <such-directive title="some str"></such-directive>
    ...
    This one uses the SuchComponent's title property:
    <such-directive [title]="title"></such-directive>
    ...
  `
})
export class SuchComponent {
  title = "OverriddenDirectiveTitle"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But What if the Directive provides the Template (aka Component which also is a Directive as you might know)

Comment: Bonus Question: What if I define a function call in the directive template: `<such-directive [title]="title" (click)="suchDirective.next()`. I imported the Directive with ViewChild but somehow I cant figure it out, getting "cant read property of undefined" in Debugging Tools.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are saying (maybe creating a new question with the details would be a good idea), but when you write `<such-directive [title]="title" (click)="suchDirective.next()` you are telling that the `SuchDirective` has an `@Output()/output` of name `click`, which when fired evaluates the expression `suchDirective.next()`. But there is no `suchDirective` variable at `SuchComponent` (the use of the `such-directive` directive doesn't create one automatically...)

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again! https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2